# adding non-failure data to failure one

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have a dataset containing features of different engines showing when they failed. I want to build supervise learning model to predict whether an engine with a certain mileage is going to fail or not. Unfortunately, I have data of engines that they never fail and I need to add them to my dataset (it is true these engines never fail but they will help model to have a better view on lifetime an engine). 
Could any one help me how to add these  non-failure data to failure one.

Best,

Comment: What is the input(s) to the model?  If the only input to your model is the type of engine, then you don't need machine learning - plain old statistics will do :) The wikipedia page on [survival analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis) might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to combine two datasets to use both for training??

If yes, you need to append one dataframe to the other. You need to make sure, that all columns/features needed for training are present in both DFs. After that you can simply append the DFs.

Python example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
>>> df.append(df2)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html